# Google Datastore 1500 byte property limit for embedded entities

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

According to: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#embedded_entity

Setting the `excludeFromIndexes: true` on an embedded entity should remove both it and its properties from being indexed and should therefore allow the properties of that embedded entity to be greater than 1500 bytes.

I am trying to write an embedded entity that has some properties that are longer than 1500 bytes and I'm getting an error:

`“Error: The value of property “additionalAttributes” is longer than 1500 bytes.    at /node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17"`

Even though I'm setting the `excludeFromIndexes: true` (and I can see in the cloud console that the embedded entity is correctly being added without indexing) on the embedded entity.

I see there is a known issue for this at: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1916. Though I don't see anything as far as a fix or workaround

Any suggestions on what is causing this and how to fix/workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My question/issue was really this one:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1916

and the answer/solution is the fixed version via this PR https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/pull/2497

Answer (score 2):

The workaround would be to set `excludeFromIndexes=true` for at least those properties that you need to support more than 1500 bytes. The JSON for your embedded entity should look like below. Note the `text` property where we are explicitly setting the `excludeFromIndexes`.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "timestampValue": "2017-06-05T18:53:23.106Z"
    },
    "text": {
      "stringValue": "long text that exceeds 1500 bytes",
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem is a large property of an embedded property, afaik you can't place `excludeFromIndexes: true` on a property of an embedded entity (or if you can, how would you do that?)

Comment: My example was indeed of an Embedded Entity from GCD console. I used the Java API which is pretty straight forward to exclude any property (top-level or nested). Not too familiar with the NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this fix to set {excludeFromIndexes: false} on all attributes recursively except three of them. The method entity.entityToEntityProto is called before the properties are sent to Datastore, but only if your entity.data is an Object (it's also possible to pass an Array).

You can include this script anywhere in node, preferably before Datastore is initiated. It will overwrite the entity.entityToEntityProto method.

```
const INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTES = ['_index','_audit','_unique'];

function entitySetIndexes(properties, path){
    for(let key in properties){
        let keypath = (path ? path+'.' : '') + key
            , prop = properties[key];

        if(prop.entityValue)
            entitySetIndexes(prop.entityValue.properties, keypath);
        else if(prop.arrayValue)
            prop.arrayValue.values.forEach(item=>{
                if(item.entityValue)
                    entitySetIndexes(item.entityValue.properties, keypath)
            });

        // excludeFromIndex cannot be set on arrays, they're always indexed
        if(!prop.arrayValue)
            prop.excludeFromIndexes = INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTES.indexOf(keypath) === -1;
    }
}

const entity = require('@google-cloud/datastore/src/entity.js')
    , entityToEntityProto = entity.entityToEntityProto;
entity.entityToEntityProto = function(entityObject){
    entityObject = entityToEntityProto(entityObject);
    entitySetIndexes(entityObject.properties);
    return entityObject;
}
```

So just make sure you save entities with {data:{attribute:'value'}, key:...}. If you want to index deep attributes, specify them delimited by dot, ignore arrays.
I'm using the script in @google-cloud/datastore v1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add `@Unindexed` annotation which will remove the index for that property and allow you to insert string property of more than 1500 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are using Go:

```
type Whatever struct {
Id           string
LongStuff    string `datastore:",noindex"`}
```

Add the `datastore:",noindex"` and it will work.